# http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response - retries exhausted or something else?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have some code that uses `requests` to get a response from an API and uploads the result into a database. I've built a custom `Request` class so I can adjust the `BACKOFF_MAX` variable. By way of an MRE:

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
from time import sleep

class RetryRequest(Retry):

    def __init__(self, backoff_max: int, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.BACKOFF_MAX = backoff_max


session = Session()
retries_spec = RetryRequest(
    total=25,
    backoff_factor=0.25,
    backoff_max=128,
)
session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries_spec))
headers = {"User-Agent": "*", "Referer": None}
session.headers.update(headers)

while True:
    response = session.get(<url>)
    # load response into database
    sleep(60)
```

This works fine for a hundreds of iterations of the loop but every so often I get this error:

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Could someone tell me whether this is the result of the retries being exhausted or whether I need some additional error handling here?

Answer (score 1):

It's more a server side error in my opinion.
It can be triggered for many reasons probably to deal with DDOS attacks, that's why I suggest you to wrap the get request by a try/except where you make your process sleep in the except part and retry.

OR

You can try to put a higher backoff factor as well